# BigDecimal setScale is not working in Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to cast json column to map. I tried udf for converting json to map. but it is not working as expected.

```
val df1 = Seq(("{\"k\":10.004}")).toDF("json")
def udfJsonStrToMapDecimal = udf((jsonStr: String)=> { var jsonMap:Map[String,Any] = parse(jsonStr).values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
     jsonMap.map{case(k,v) => (k,BigDecimal.decimal(v.asInstanceOf[Double]).setScale(6))}.toMap
})
val f = df1.withColumn("map",udfJsonStrToMapDecimal($"json"))
scala> f.printSchema
root
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)
 |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: decimal(38,18) (valueContainsNull = true)
```

**instead of decimal(38,6) it converting the value as decimal(38,18)**
Need help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default decimal precesion is `DecimalType(38, 18)`, I am not sure what you are trying to do but

You can cast the current decimal type as

```
df1.withColumn("map",udfJsonStrToMapDecimal($"json").cast("map<string, decimal(38,6)>"))
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)
 |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: decimal(38,6) (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Or you can also define the schema and read as JSON directly as

```
val schema = StructType(StructField("k", DecimalType(38, 6), nullable = false) :: Nil)

val df1 = Seq(("{\"k\":10.004}")).toDF("json")

val result = df1.withColumn("value", from_json($"json", schema))
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- json: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- k: decimal(38,6) (nullable = true)
```